# getUser() returns 0 when logged in

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, user

I've tried moving my site and my script to get the Joomla User Information is returning 0 (the guest account) despite being logged in.

The only change I had to make, once moving servers, was the location of the $JRoot folder to match the new server layout.

```
<?php
$temp = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$temp = str_replace("one_url", "another_url", $temp);
if($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] =='::1') {
    $JRoot = $temp;
} else {
    $JRoot = $temp;
}
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', $JRoot );
define('JPATH_ROOT', $JRoot );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
$defines = $JRoot . "/includes/defines.php";
$framework = $JRoot . "/includes/framework.php";
echo "defines: " . $defines . "<br />";
echo "DS:" . DS  . "<br />";
require_once ($defines);
require_once ($framework);

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

function GetJoomUser() {
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $JomUser['id'] = $user->id;
    $JomUser['usergroups'] = $user->groups; 
    $JomUser['username'] = $user->username;
    print_r($user);
    return $JomUser;
}
function getJoomlaUsername($id) {
    $user = JFactory::getUser($id);
    $username=$user->get('username');
    return $username;
}
```

This code is working because I've used file_exists statements (in testing) to assure defines & framework are being found.

When logged in, I can see my User Profile so I know that I'm successfully logged in.

So why is $user printing out the Guest information?

Comment: Do you only have 1 Joomla site hosted on your new server?

Comment: Yes... But since it is being called directly from a browser and pointing specifically to the directory of Joomla shouldn't it not make a difference?  I ask because I have another site that will have multiple Joomla installations that will use this code as well.

Comment: Ok, where is your script located in regards to the Root of your Joomla installation? For example `JOOMLA_ROOT/folder/myscript.php`

Comment: public_html/MyApp/_includes/php/GetJoomUser.php   and Joomla_Root is public_html/site.com/cms

Comment: I just tested while looking at the database table _session.   The Guest User is not present until I call this file.  Upon call, it is creating the guest login record in _session

Comment: you should be able to get everything with JFactory::getUser(), I am not entirely sure why you are using that second function to get user info. $user->username returns the same thing that your second function is returning. But it looks like you already knew that since you called $user->username in your first function.

It appears that you are instantiating a new Joomla session by calling the framework again, which would explain why you are seeing the guest info. If you are going to use the framework this way you may need to bind the user first as logged in, then get the current users info.

Comment: Terry - thanks for your response.   The 2nd function is looking for the username of a specific user (not the logged in user).   I commented that out, but it did not resolve the issue of showing the guest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I solved the problem.   It was all based on the new structure and the cookies.

I had to set System->Global Configuration->Cookie Domain to '.p3proswing.com' (as this is were the pages that reference this stored (stored in p3proswing.com/P3Live).

Next I needed to be sure all my menu items are pointed to www.p3proswing.com/P3Live/.... urls.

Then it writes the cookie to www.p3proswing.com and reads from it when the pages call the GetUserInfo3.php file.

Answer (score 1):

So I've tried replicating your directory path and I **believe** you may have set the paths up incorrectly.

```
The following worked for me:

<?php

// Constants
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../site.com/cms'));
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Require
require_once JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php';

// Application
JFactory::getApplication('site')->initialise();

// Funtions
function GetJoomUser()
{
    $user = JFactory::getUser();

    $JomUser['id']         = $user->id;
    $JomUser['usergroups'] = $user->groups; 
    $JomUser['username']   = $user->username;

    return $JomUser;
}

function getJoomlaUsername($id)
{
    $user = JFactory::getUser($id);

    return $user->get('username');
}

// Call functions
$GetJoomUser       = GetJoomUser();
$getJoomlaUsername = getJoomlaUsername($GetJoomUser['id']);

// Dump Data
var_dump($GetJoomUser);
var_dump($getJoomlaUsername);
```

Try replacing all the code in your PHP file with the above code.

It returned the following for me:

```
array (size=3)
  'id' => string '244' (length=3)
  'usergroups' => 
    array (size=1)
      8 => string '8' (length=1)
  'username' => string 'Lodder' (length=9)

string 'Lodder' (length=9)
```

On a side note, your `GetJoomUser` is pointless. There's no need to create a new array of object values when you can simply call each one like so:

```
$user->id;
$user->groups; 
$user->username;
```

Comment: Actually, I think I found the root cause:  Upon initial login, it creates a cookie in Chrome for p3live.com.p3proswing.com (linked to user p3.chuck [my username]). Once the script is run, it creates a second cookie for www.p3live.com (which is linked to a Guest session). So, it would appear it is then reading the p3live.com cookie to get the current user. I imagine it is creating this cookie because it does not find one for www.p3live.com. Now I just need to know who to set it so the cookie is correct

Comment: `JFactory::getUser()` get's the user object based on database data, not cookies...I believe